# Motherboard starting up as soon as I plug in power but no response from any Input or output device

Tags: motherboard

this is a bizarre case happening to my nephew's Computer
Motherboard: H61M-K from ASUS
As soon as I plug in the power supply computer starts up but there is no display, nor the laser of mouse is turning on or the numlock of keyboard is turning on. Just the motherboard starts without accepting any commands, nor it is listening to power switch buttons. HDD and DVD reader/writer is starting normally but as I get closer and try to listen, I can hear computer's startup sounds again and again indicating that the motherboard is restarting again and again.

Symptoms:-

```
No power in USB keyboard
No power in USB mouse
No power to VGA Cable
CPU fan is running
HDD is spinning
DVD writer is good
No response to power buttons
```

also the monitor isn't showing "No VGA port connected" or something like that meaning that it knows that something is connected but still no display.

What I have tried:-

```
Resetting BIOS by removing CMOS battery
I forcefully stopped CPU fan with my finger but detected auto restart every few seconds
disconnecting HDD
changing VGA
power supply is no problem
```

Comment: You don't even have to press the power button? Try a different PSU

Comment: Some biose's have a setting that enables automatic power on after power loss, you can disable this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on personal experience in debugging these sort of things, there are number of further steps you can take.

1. Verify that the jumper pin configuration / button connectors from the case
   https://www.manualowl.com/m/Asus/H61M-K/Manual/350796?page=41

   > nor it is listening to power switch buttons

   This would indicate to me that there might be something amiss there
2. Disconnect / Reconnect RAM modules one by one and try powering up with 0,1,2 modules plugged in depending how many you have
3. Try to listen for any error code beep-ing, this is usually a good indicator of what's going on -> CPU problems should make audible "beep" errors, if there are none then most likely problem with MotherBoard